# Socket.io - Cannot load file

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, laravel, laravel-4

I made a web chat application using Node.js, socket.io and express. It's working well.
Now I want to move my chat application into my website but i have problem with paths.
My website is based on **[Laravel framework](http://four.laravel.com)** and has this structure.

```
Website
    /public
        /js
            /jquery1-10.js
            /chat.js        ----> client side chat file.
    /app.js                 ----> node.js server side file.
    /index.php
```

Laravel use layouts so in `index.php` file,  `URL::asset('/path-to-file')` is working well for all files inside public directory. including stylesheets and javascript.

Inside my `index.php` file I call javascripts this way:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery1-10.js'); }}" ></script> // public/js/jquery1-10.js
<script src="{{ asset('js/chat.js'); }}" ></script>  // public/js/chat.js
<script src="{{ asset('/socket.io/socket.io.js'); }}" ></script> // ???
```

both `jquery1-10.js` and `chat.js` loads well
BUT can't load socket.io file. I think socket.io creates automatically! and I have no idea where it is.
Can somebody help me with this?

this is `app.js` file:

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express"),
app = express(),
server = http.createServer(app),
io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
server.listen(4000);

app.get("/*", function( req, res ) {
    res.sendfile( __dirname + "/index.php" );
});
```

And this is my chat.js file --> client side.

```
jQuery( function($){
var socket = io.connect(); ---> error happens here. can not load socket.io.js file
```

---

## Solved

well, I used this line:
`<script src="http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js" ></script>`

instead of this:
`<script src="{{ asset('/socket.io/socket.io.js'); }}" ></script>`

and it worked well.

Comment: Can you add some code how are you binding socket.io and your webserver?

Comment: post the request for socket.io.js executed in web console.

Comment: so it was the same problem!!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you fix or find any solution for this? I have the same problem, though it should work when you put your IP address on your `io.connect parameter`.

Example:

```
io.connect("YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:4000")
```