# Why does not sending data io.sockets.emit and socket.broadcast.emit

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Tried different methods, but the data is sent to a maximum of one or two clients. How to send data to all the clients connected to the server ? What am I doing wrong?

Server.js:

```
    var PORT = 3000;

    var options = {
        // 'log level': 0
    };

    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var http = require('http');
    var server = http.createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, options);
    server.listen(PORT);

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.sendfile(__dirname + '/attantions/templates/.default/template.php');
    });

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
      client.on('attantion', function (data) {
        try {
          // Tried so
          io.sockets.volatile.emit('attantion', data);
          // And tried so
          io.sockets.emit('attantion', data);
          client.emit('attantion', data);
          client.broadcast.emit('attantion', data );
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
          client.disconnect();
        }
      });
    });
```

Client.js:

```
    socket.emit("attantion", data);
    socket.on('attantion', function (data) {
      pushData(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

See this post for different options for socket.io messages

[Send response to all clients except sender (Socket.io)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058226/send-response-to-all-clients-except-sender-socket-io)

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
  client.on('attantion', function (data) {
    //client.emit('attantion', data ); // This will send it to only the client 
    //client.broadcast.emit('attantion', data); // This will send it to everyone but this client
    io.emit('attantion', data);  // This will send it to all attached sockets. 

  });
});
```

**Edit**

I wonder if this post can help you?

[Socket.io - Cannot load file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317654/socket-io-cannot-load-file)

I was curious how sending the php file to the client through node.js works? are you using another framework?

Could you show more of what your client code looks like? loading the lib and the instantiation of the socket.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this method. Just tried io.sockets.emit('attantion', data); It doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure you have a connection?

Comment: Yes, when I will push the date to the server, I can see it through the console log.

Comment: but when I try to return the date in the console log on the client comes nothing